# Retrieving records from another SQL Server database - Umbraco

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, umbraco7

I'm working on a website, where I need to retrieve pricelists, from another database on the same SQL Server as my Umbraco database.

It's a requirement that it has to be in a separate database.

I have made a new connection string `Pricelist` and used EF database-first.

`PriceList` repository:

```
namespace UmbracoCMS.Repository{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public partial class Prisliste
{
    public string Kode { get; set; }
    public string Speciale { get; set; }
    public string Ydelsesgruppe { get; set; }
    public string Gruppe { get; set; }
    public string Ydelse { get; set; }
    public string Ydelsestekst { get; set; }
    public string Anaestesi { get; set; }
    public string Indlæggelse { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Listepris { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> WebSort { get; set; }
    public string YdelsesTekstDK { get; set; }
    public string Frapris { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Sortering { get; set; }
   } 
}
```

`PriceListController` class:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

using UmbracoCMS.Repository;

namespace UmbracoCMS.Controllers{

   public class PriceListController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController {

   [HttpGet]
   public PartialViewResult GetPriceList(string contentTitle){

      var db = new PricelistContext();


      var query = from b in db.Prislistes orderby b.Speciale select b;

      Console.WriteLine("records in the database:");

      foreach (var item in query)
      {
        Console.WriteLine(item.Speciale);
      }

      return PartialView("~/views/partials/PriceList.cshtml");
    }
  }
}
```

What I want is to load the prices for a treatment, based on a property on the document type. I'm just not sure how do this in umbraco since I'm fairly new a umbraco.

So when a treatment page is requested, I need to take the property `ContentTitle` value. Use it to retrieve all records with the same `Speciale` and display them in a list/table.

With a query

```
.where(b.Speciale = contentTitle)
```

It would be great if someone could help a little, or lead me in the right direction.

Also is it possible to do it in the same http request? Or should I use partial view or macros to both get the properties of the document type, from the umbraco database, and the records from the pricelist database at the same time when a user go to the treatment page?

Or is there a better way to do this?

## **Update:**

Thanks a lot, for the great answer Ryios.

I got a question more.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace UmbracoCMS.Controllers
{
  public class PriceListSurfaceController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
  {

      public ActionResult GetPriceList(string contentTitle)
      {
        
          PricelistContext.RunInContext(db =>
          {
              var result = db.Prislistes.OrderBy(p => p.Speciale);
            
          });

          return View(result);
      }
   }
}
```

I got it working, so it call the method and the data from the Pricelist Database is shown in:

```
var result = db.Prislistes.OrderBy(p => p.Speciale);
```

Now I just need to get the list of prices out to the view again, so I can show a list or table of the prices.

Do you have a suggestion on how I can this in Umbraco. Normally I would return a ViewModel in MVC like:

```
return View(new ListViewModel(result));
```

and use it in the view like:

```
@model Project.ViewModels.ListViewModel
```

So I can loop through it.

But I want to still have the properties from the the "Home"/"TreatmentPage" Document type.

Should I do it with a partialView or is there a better way?

## **Solved**

I thought I wanted to share it, if anyone else is in a similar situaction.

Controller:

```
namespace UmbracoCMS.Controllers
{
    public class PriceListSurfaceController : Umbraco.Web.Mvc.SurfaceController
    {



        public PartialViewResult PriceList(string contentTitle)
        {
            List<Prisliste> result = null; 

            PricelistContext.RunInContext(db =>
            {
                result = db.Prislistes.Where(p => p.Speciale == contentTitle)
                     .OrderBy(p => p.Speciale).ToList();  
            });

            var model = result.Select( pl => new PrislistVm()
           {
               Speciale = pl.Speciale,
               Listepris= pl.Listepris
           });

           return PartialView(model);
       }



   }

}
```

ViewModel:

```
namespace UmbracoCMS.ViewModels
{
    public class PrislistVm
    {

       public PrislistVm()
       {
           Results = new List<Prisliste>();
       }

       public List<Prisliste> Results { get; set; } 

       public string Speciale { get; set; }
       public double listepris { get; set; }
   }
}
```

View/PriceListSurface:

```
@model IEnumerable<UmbracoCMS.ViewModels.PrislistVm>
       
@{
     ViewBag.Title = "PriceList";
}

 <h2>PriceList</h2>



      @foreach (var item in Model)
      {
            @item.Speciale
            @item.Listepris
      }
```

Comment: I suggest that you set up database permissions so that one database has permission to query the other.  Then get the data you need with a single query.

Comment: Just create some views in the "remote" database and synonyms to those views in "local" database and EF won't know the difference. If they need to updatable then you can put triggers on the views or simply make the synonyms to the tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Your going to have a memory leak if you load your EF context like that.  I recommend creating a method to wrap it for you with a llambda callback.  Put it in your context class.

   ```
   public static void RunInContext(Action<PricelistContext> contextCallBack)
   {
       PricelistContext dbContext = null;
       try
       {
           dbContext = new PricelistContext();
           contextCallBack(dbContext);
       }
       finally
       {
           dbContext.Dispose();
           dbContext = null;
       }
   }

   //Example Call
   PricelistContext.RunInContext(db => {
       var result = db.PrisListes.OrderBy(p => p.Speciale);
       //loop through your items
   });
   ```
2. To get the Value of the DocumentType, it depends on the calling context.  Assuming you are using a Razor Template that is attached to the document type, that is associated with a Content Page.

   ```
   @inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoTemplatePage
   @{
       Layout = "ContentPageLayout.cshtml";
   }
   @* Call GetPriceList on PriceListController with Parameter contentTitle *@
   @Html.Action("GetPriceList", "PriceListSurface", new { contentTitle =     Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<string>("ContentTitle") });
   ```

In the above example, I have created a document type with a property called ContentTitle that is associated with a view called ContentPage.  Then I created content in the backoffice Content section called "Home" that uses the document type.  Giving me a url like

```
http://localhost/home
```

Also, your SurfaceController will not work.  Umbraco's logic for mapping the routes for surface controllers has some requirements for your surface controller's naming conventions.  You have to end the name of the class with "SurfaceController" and then it get's called PriceListSurfaceController, then it maps the controller with a name of "PriceListSurface".

Here's the documentation for the SurfaceController features.

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/surface-controllers

Using a surface controller is the right logic.  It's not good practice to have your Data Layer code calls in the UmbracoTemplatePage.  1, because RazorTemplates are interpreted/compiled and SurfaceController's are JIT compiled int the dll, so SurfaceController code is WAY faster. 2 Because you can make asynchronous Controller calls in MVC Razor.  If it was all in the view it would make it really difficult to convert everything to be asynchronous.  It's best to keep server side logic in a controller.

Optionally, you can Hijack an Umbraco route and replace it with a custom controller that doesn't have to inherit from SurfaceController, which makes it possibly to surface content to the browser that is or isn't part of umbraco.

http://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Reference/Mvc/custom-controllers

You can also create a new section in the backoffice to manage your Price List "the ui framework for building one is written against AngularJS"

http://www.enkelmedia.se/blogg/2013/11/22/creating-custom-sections-in-umbraco-7-part-1.aspx

Comment: [Yes, you *should* `Dispose` things that are `IDisposable` but I doubt you'll get a memory leak](http://blog.jongallant.com/2012/10/do-i-have-to-call-dispose-on-dbcontext.html#.U7OYovmSxHM). And why wouldn't you simply use `using` instead of `try ... finally`? This is ASP.NET MVC, so just let an IoC container do the lifetime management for you. And then look! No more hard to test methods that rely on static methods in another class.

Comment: I use try finally, because it's a partial from what I use.  The one I use has a catch there and I have an error tracking system that logs all uncaught database errors in Sql Server.

I use the method because I don't want to write that logic everytime I use my context.  It cleanly wraps the context with all of my logic in a way that I can just do

ContextClass.RunInContext(p => {
  //do stuff here
});

The code that's wrapped around that Action<ContextClass> is in a try  catch, logs errors, and does other stuff.

When it's done, if there was an error, it throws it back out.

Comment: That way when the system is live and theres 1000 users hitting it, I have a log of all the errors that have occurred, what url they were on, stack trace, logged in user, etc etc etc.

Comment: Thanks Ryios it worked.

I just got one more Question? 

I have Updated the Question cause theres a limit on how much I can write in those comments.

Can you help me with a last question, or lead me in the right direction. 

How do I get the result back to the View (page), so I can Loop through the list and display the list along side the other information fromt the document type?

Comment: An example of how to display the results is already in my answer after #2.